# Can black navigationbar title color change?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My `navigationBar` is black:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

but can not change textcolor in title, it has no effect, why?

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIColor whiteColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName, nil];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Comment: Are you trying to set the title from storyboard of your `UIViewController`? If yes, then you should select the *navigation item* in your storyboard and set its title. It should automatically be white.

Comment: from code, no sb exist

Comment: And its not white by default? Could it be the text isn't getting set?

Comment: Do you have `setTitleTextAttributes` code in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method or where?

Comment: @RajeshkumarR I tried at many places to put this code

Comment: I've tried all answers and everything worked for me. Can you share your project in dropbox?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                            [UIColor whiteColor],UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                            [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                            [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(-1, 0)], UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset, nil];

[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code.You can change your title color easily :)**

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = White;
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden=NO;
self.navigationItem.title = @"yourTitle";
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
 @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:White}];
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   [[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:kBoldFontName size:16],NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor blueColor]}];
```

It is working fine for me please try once.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below code it is working fine.I am using Xcode 8 and iOS 10.2

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;

self.navigationItem.title = @"your Title here";

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]}];

self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

[image]